# Redirecionamento Magento

Tags: php, magento

Eu tenho dois ambientes de um e-commerce em Magento: homologação e produção. O problema é o seguinte: quando vou fazer o login em homologação, ele me redireciona para produção. Na tela de login de homologação, o action do `<form>` está indo para o servidor de Produção, quando na verdade deveria ir para homologação, porém o link que ele deve fazer o post é recebido pelo código PHP `<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>`, que nesse caso deveria receber o link de homologação, certo? Alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Limpou a cache do magento? Verificou se está a apontar (veja no XML) para a base de dados correta onde os links apontam para homologação? Verificou se a base de dados tem os links corretos? Verificou se existe algum redirect no ".htaccess"? Se depois disso não funcionar, apelando apague a cache do browser, reiniciei o computador, mude de cadeira...

Answer (score 1):

Acesse a base de dados de onde está instalado o Magento e altere a tabela CORE_CONFIG_DATA para a nova localização, basta alterar os valores do campo “path” da tabela que são respectivamente: web/unsecure/base_url e web/secure/base_url);

Caso não se recorde em qual banco de dados esta instalado seu Magento, acesse o arquivo 'local.xml' na pasta:

**app/etc**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Rafael, mas os links do base_url já estão apontando para o ambiente de homologação. Isso que me deixou com mais dúvida quanto ao problema, pois mesmo com os links apontando para o ambiente de homologação, ele cai em produção. No momento eu resolvi o direcionamento no hardcode, mas não é o melhor caminho.

Answer (score 0):

Corrigir esse problema é bem simples – há inclusive duas maneiras de se resolver rapidamente.

A primeira maneira, que vejo como mais simples, é acessar o banco de dados da sua aplicação e modificar direto as URLs nos campos `“web/unsecure/base_url”` e `“web/secure/base_url”`, que ficam na tabela `“core_config_data”`.

Depois disso, basta apagar todo o conteúdo da pasta `/var/cache` e… voila!.

Comment: Ambos já estão indicando para homologação, mas mesmo assim o link do post está indo para produção...

Comment: Lembrando sempre de apagar todo conteudo de cache "TODO"

Comment: Limpar o cache pelo admin não é o suficiente?

Comment: Atualizando as informações: Conferi no banco de dados e as "base_url" estão com o link de homologacao. E já apaguei tudo da pasta /var/cache, porém nada mudou.

Comment: apaga tudo do /var

Comment: se com isso não for ta muito estranho isso ai